# one query with groupby / count / select new

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to make in c# a query with linq to sql. I can handle it in sql but in linq to
sql is the result not what I wanted to get.
So there is a table with:

- a day, in datetime with date and time
- and a kind of id

I have to count the ids for each date, the time isn't important. So the result
should be something like:

```
day: 2013-11-12 amountIDs: 4
```

People said to me, I can make a select new query and in this query I can set the day
and could count the ids, or I make a group by day. I read similar question, but it doesn't work in my case.

Could somebody help me?

I tried it with the statement below, but the days have to be grouped, so now the output is foreach datetime, like this

```
day: 12.12.2013 12:00:00 amountIDs: 1
day: 12.12.2013 12:10:10 amountIDs: 1
```

In sql I made this statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), data.dayandtime, 106) AS day, count(data.amountIds) as ids 
FROM data
WHERE ( data.dayandtime >= DATEADD(day, -28, getdate()) AND (data.type = 100) AND (data.isSomething = 0) )
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), data.dayandtime, 106), data.isSomthing and it works.
```

I saw similar cases, where people made a : from-select-new xyz statement, than I made a view of it and tried to group just the view. Like this

```
var query = data.GroupBy(g => g.day.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Show us the query; provide your steps to convert it into a LinqToSql query, this way we perhaps can tell you where you went wrong

Comment: I rewrote my question. Is it more specific now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var qry = from data in dbContext   
           group data by data.day into dataGrpd
                  select new
                  {
                      day= dataGrpd.Key,
                      amountIDs= dataGrpd.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count()
                  };
```

[Check This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea#Simple1)

Comment: I changed: data.day to data.day.Value.toShortDateString(). Now it works how I want it. Thanks!